# Indentation on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting

Why does indentation go off if I add space in between?

Without space:

[image]

With space:

[image]

Comment: Because lists are weird with code, and it looks like it's trying to format that as a numbered list. (Notice in the second preview that the "2." is indented slightly?) Try adding an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) between the "2." line and the code block. That should help. (Note that there are other things, even as simple as `<!>`, that you can put in there. They _do_ work, but they shouldn't. In case SO fixes that later, I recommend sticking with a regular HTML comment.)

Comment: Now if you mean for that to be an actual numbered list... You _can_ have code blocks in a list, you just have to indent the code 8 spaces rather than 4.

Comment: So, its better to avoid list items if we have code?

Comment: Oh, no, you don't have to avoid list items if you're using code. You just have to learn how to work around the little quirks with it. There are plenty of times when it's 100% appropriate to use code with lists. It looks like you have a good usage for it, in example.